# How can I create several related JComboboxes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I want to create three `JCombobox`es and link them together. For example, in this picture:

[image: university, college and department JComboboxes]

when a selection is made for "university," the college combobox should show only colleges of the selected university. Similarly, only departments of the selected college should be shown next to the "Department:" label.

Comment: The question is not clear for me. Do you want simply putting them in one JPanel or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say you have a few universities, each has a number of colleges and each college has a number of departments. I think Tofiq wants to restrict the college selections to just the ones for the selected university and after the college has been selected to the existing departments of that college. I would chain the ComboBoxModels for that.

Comment: I assume the target is the layout - three JComboBox instances layouted in one column. You can achieve that via GridBoxLayout or simpler via GridLayout.

Comment: @Costis Aivalis I also agree with Robert, it's probably layout issue rather then app. logic issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to extend the approach shown in this [`ComboTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191882) example.

Comment: It correct for two combobox, because it worked by indexing but I have three combobox.

Comment: Yes; one simple expedient is to make `models` a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: +1 for the approach of changing the model on the combo box ActionEvent. @Tofiq, you've been given the approach. How you organize or retrieve the data is a design issue that you must solve. If the data is small then you may hard code (or load the data when the program is loaded. Or if it is large you may decide to do a database query in the ActionEvent. Or you may have a combination of both approaches.