# Can't write to textbox in a Swing application executed from console via ssh

Tags: java, swing, console, ssh

I made a swing application with a JFrame. But when I execute this application from the console with java -jar when I am logged via ssh, I cannot write in any of the textboxes. Everything that I write appears in the console rather than in the textbox. See the image attached to show what happens. How can I solve this? Thank you very much in advance.

[The problem http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/8688/screenshotoftheproblem.jpg](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/8688/screenshotoftheproblem.jpg)

Javier

Comment: I do not know, but I think that it could be easily installed.

Comment: Success with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191837/dynamic-jcomboboxes/3191882#3191882) on Ubuntu (client, Java 6) and Mac (server, X11.app). What OS's are you using.

Comment: I am using ArchLinux in my machine and Debian Squeeze in the remote machine.

Comment: @Javier: Any better luck with my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191837/dynamic-jcomboboxes/3191882#3191882)?

Comment: The problem with your example is that there isn't any textbox in it. I can click on any button of the GUI, but I cannot introduce any text.

Comment: In your screen shot, it looks like the console has focus (the close/min/max buttons are colored). If you click on the text box, does that window get the focus?

Comment: Now that you say it, the window does never get the focus. I click on the window but it does not get the focus.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also but solved by using ssh -Y (instead of -X). Found on forums that some java applications requires trusted (-Y) ssh to work properly. Hope that help others.

Comment: this helped in my case when trying to install an oracle db

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are dealing with unix like operative systems, even you don't mention it. What version of JVM are you using? Is the same version in your ssh server and client? I had a problem with OS X's JVM, I could not run GUI through ssh from a Linux client, but between same Linux flavour, there were no problems. You might want  to add debug output to your ssh command line, through "-v" switch.  I would recommend trying a very simple application, a trivial example: just a text box on a JFrame; to rule out any possible layout stack or listener issues.

Could you try these code, and see if you can modify  the JTextField

```
public class SimplestGUI extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        SimplestGUI window = new SimplestGUI();
        window.start();
    }

    public SimplestGUI()
    {
        initGUI();  
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(150,100);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setText("123 probando");
        getContentPane().add(textField);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To compile and run use these command (assuming you have a JDK on your PATH):

```
javac SimplestGUI.java ; java -cp . SimplestGUI
```

If that works, then you should start adding your components, listener, adapters, etc. one by one, and see which one is causing the text fields not getting the input. 
If doesn't work either, then my guess is that you might have a problem with different X Window versions or implementations.
¿Can you share your code to try it on another environment?

Comment: That is the only output I get about the program execution.

`debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 34408
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
`
My ssh is: OpenSSH_5.8p2, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
The Host OpenSSH version is: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

Comment: I copied the code but did not work, I cannot edit the textbox.

Comment: Could you try with your ssh session, if your input are being caught with a simple X Window application: xcalc or xterm?

Comment: Could you try the SimplestGUI within a virtual machine using the exactly same installation (Linux and JVM) than your ssh server?