# JComboBox item listener

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener, comboboxmodel

I have two combo boxes. The first contains some operator (+ , - ,* ,/) and the second one contains some value from 0 to 10. When user select (/) in first combo box I want the second one to show a value from 2 to 10 instead of 0 to 10.

I've tried this:

```
String[] operators = {"+","-" ,"*", "/"};

String[] number = {"0","1","3"....."10"};

divisionModel= new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"2","3","4","5".."10"});



    operatorCombo = new JComboBox(operators);

    numberCombo = new JComboBox(number);


operatorCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {


    if (operatorCombo .getSelectedItem().equals("/")){

        numberCombo .setModel(divisionModel);
  }
```

my problem is when I select ("/") the numberCombo works fine and show me numbers from 2 to 10 but when I click on another operator it still show me the numbers from 2 to 10 instead 0 to 10.How can I solve this problem?! 
Thanks

Comment: !) There is no `ComboBox` in Swing.  Did you mean `JComboBox`?  If so, copy/paste the name.  If not, don't mix Swing & AWT Components. 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: divisionModel =  new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"2","3"....});
         if (operatorCombo.getSelectedItem()== "/"){
            operatorCombo.setModel(divisionModel );

Comment: this code is work when I select (/) but I dont know what should to do when I re-select another item for example + because it is not showing all items another time just from 2 to 10

Answer (score 2):

```
// always compare objects using equals()
if (operatorCombo.getSelectedItem().equals("/")) {..
```

As to updating the 2nd combo, create a new model for it and call [`setModel(ComboBoxModel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29).

Comment: yes I did that and work fine when I select (/) but my problem is when I select another operator like + ,secondCombo suppose to show all number from 0 to 10 but it just show from 2 to 10

Comment: I did not recommend you post *"the code"*, I recommended you post ***an SSCCE.***  Follow the link, read the document.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513) that shows how the selection made in one `JComboBox` can change the appearance of related `JComboBox` by using a different `DefaultComboBoxModel`.