# Return JCombobox values to 'original' list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

In my code if a user selects Production the channels that are available are changed but if the user decides to selects 'Staging' or 'Test' the full list of channels should display.  When this happens what displays is `[Ljava.lang.String;@1c23f1bb` instead.  What will correct this behavior?  I am newby with java.

Below is my code and when I set the environmentCbx to something other than "Production" I don't get the original string array `communityNameString` in the community combobox.

```
String communityNameString[] = {"Connection","CDK","Governors", "Community", "Committee", "Center","All States","Community_2","Sandbox"};


  environmentCbx.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      JComboBox environmentCbx = (JComboBox)ae.getSource();
      String environmentName = (String)environmentCbx.getSelectedItem();
      if("Production".equals(environmentName))
      {
          communityCbx.removeAllItems();
          //communityCbx.addItem(productionCommunityNames);
          communityCbx.addItem("Associate");
      }
      else
      {
          communityCbx.removeAllItems();
          communityCbx.addItem(communityNameString);
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513), you can have more than one `ComboBoxModel`, and you can change them as required. Simply build two models: one containing the full list and the other containing the subset.

Addendum: Reading more closely, the symbol `[Ljava.lang.String;@1c23f1bb` is an artifact of the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method as applied to a `String []`. An item is expected to be an individual `Object`, such as `String`; you have added an entire array of `String` instances.