# How do I use the value in 2 JComboBox's in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

What I am attempting to do is create 2 JComboBox's and 2 JTextField box's.  I need to be able to write code that uses the temperature type (Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin) in the first JComboBox and converts that first temperature type into whichever temperature type has been selected in the 2nd JComboBox.  This must be done by using whatever number has been entered into the first JTextField box (that will be the initial value of the selected temp type) and converted into the new temperature type in the 2nd JTextField box.  Here is how far I've progressed...

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at line 40 when I run my test, and I don't know if I have formatted the double used in the if statement correctly to have the new value appear again as a String in the 2nd JTextField box.  Before i go through with writing all of the other if statements to handle all of the other scenarios, I am looking for some pointers on if what I have done up till this point is correct.

```
package temperatureConverter;


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TempConverter extends JFrame
{
    private JComboBox firstComboBox;
    private JComboBox secondComboBox;
    private JTextField initialTemp;
    private JTextField convertedTemp;
    //private enum TempType { FAHRENHEIT, CELSIUS, KELVIN};
    private static final String[] tempType = { "Fahrenheit", "Celsius", "Kelvin" }; 

    public TempConverter()
    {
        super("Temperature Converter");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        firstComboBox = new JComboBox(tempType);
        firstComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        firstComboBox.addItemListener(null);
        add(firstComboBox);
        secondComboBox = new JComboBox(tempType);
        secondComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        secondComboBox.addItemListener(null);
        add(secondComboBox);
        initialTemp = new JTextField ("", 10);
        initialTemp.addActionListener(null);
        add(initialTemp);
        convertedTemp = new JTextField ("", 10);
        convertedTemp.addActionListener(null);
        add(convertedTemp);
    }
    String theInitialTempType = (String) firstComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String theTempTypeToConvertTo = (String) secondComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String theChosenTemp = initialTemp.getSelectedText();
    String theNewTemp = convertedTemp.getSelectedText();

    private class textHandler implements ItemListener
    {
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event)
        {
            double convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = Double.parseDouble(theChosenTemp);
            double convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = Double.parseDouble(theNewTemp);
            //String string1 = "";
            //String string2 = "";

            if ( theInitialTempType == tempType[0] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[1] )
            {
                 convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp   -  32)  *  5 / 9; 
                 String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Finally edited! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String theInitialTempType = (String) firstComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

This code line is outside the constructor where the field is created.  The attributes are used in other methods of the class, so the declaration `String theAttribute` needs to be outside the constructor.

On the other hand, the creation/initialization of the instance needs to be done after other fields are created, so at the end of the constructor, `theAttribute = anotherAttribute.getSelectedText();`

But even that is not correct.  The fields are empty at that stage, so it makes no sense to try calculating results from them.  Calculations should be controlled by the end user, and done on action.  Look into `ActionListener` - it can be added to fields and will fire on <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thompsonwhen I do that I get indicators in my if statement below saying the two arguments cant be resolved to variables.

Comment: No i was saying sorry about not getting the @Andrew Thompson out correctly.  When I do what you suggested the arguments in the if statement below highlight in red(eclipse IDE). Can you give me a hint on how I am supposed to get the value in my if statement to show up in the 2nd JTextfield box?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  To make the current code into an SSCCE, add a `main` that shows the GUI in a `JOptionPane` or `JFrame`.

Comment: Jremy: You'll have to move the initialization for all four [instance variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) into the constructor. And don't forget to `pack()`!

Comment: pack()? what do you mean? new term.

Comment: [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29), shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12224343/230513).

Answer (score 2):

As you have two instances of `JComboBox`, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513) shows how a selection in the first combo can change what's shown in the second combo. For example, selecting `Fahrenheit` in the first combo would change the second combo's model to display only `Celsius` or `Kelvin`. Etc.

Addendum: As @Andrew suggests, you'll have to move the initialization for all four [instance variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) into the constructor. Here's the `main()` I used to test your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TempConverter f = new TempConverter();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See also [`CelsiusConverterGUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/).

Comment: I don't need for that to happen.  What I'm trying to have happen is the value that a person inputs to the 1st JTextfield box should represent the value in degrees of the temp type in the first JComboBox and in the 2nd JtextField box should then be converted to the new temperature that should correlate to whatever type of temperature scale has been selected in the 2nd JComboBox.

Comment: OK, it's just a way to avoid the identity conversion. Updated to expand on @Andrew's suggestion. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: thanks to the both of you for your help! I'm going to rearrange the code and see what new questions arise.  I appreciate what you've done for me to this point.