# Need help on itemStateChanged on JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have three JComboBox, one for continents, one for countries and another for cities. All data is loaded from a database.

The first JComboBox has all continents. When I select one of them, the second JComboBox is loaded with the respective countries. Until now works, because I added an "itemStateChanged".

However, when I select a country, the event "itemStateChanged" is called again.
What makes my second combo box stay with the first item selected, or (if I do the "RemoveAllItems") duplicates its content?

There is no way in which it created a "itemStateChanged" for each JComboBox? Of the kind .NET, in which it is possible to create a "SelectedIndexChanged" for each combo box?

Some parts of my code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ItemListener 
{
…
private String iddistrito="VAZIO!!!";
private String idmunicipio="VAZIO!!!"; 
private boolean limpa=false;
private boolean populardistritos=false;
private boolean popularmunicipios=false;
private JComboBox cbFreguesiacliente = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox cbmunicipiocliente = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox cbdistritocliente = new JComboBox();
…
private void jbInit() throws Exception {
…
cbmunicipiocliente.addItemListener(this);
cbdistritocliente.addItemListener(this);     
…
}
```

This part of code is the content when i click on the button, to enable my components:

```
private void btnNovocliente_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    populardistritos = true;
    cbdistritocliente.removeAllItems();
    preenchecbdistritos();
    populardistritos = false;
}
```

This piece of code fills the contents of the first JComboBox:

```
private void preenchecbdistritos(){
        query = "select Distrito from distritos;";
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
            StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultset.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            cbdistritocliente.addItem("");
            while (resultset.next()) {
                for (int i =1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    if (metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("Distrito")) {
                        cbdistritocliente.addItem(resultset.getObject(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"rebentou no 1º catch " + e.toString(),"Inane error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"rebentou no 2º catch " + e.toString(),"Inane error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
}
```

This is the famous event, which would like to get individually for each JComboBox:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (populardistritos == false) {
        if (limpa == false) {
            if ((!cbdistritocliente.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) && (idmunicipio.equals("VAZIO!!!")))
            {
                query = "select id_distrito from distritos where distrito = '" + cbdistritocliente.getSelectedItem().toString() + "';";
                try{
                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
                    StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultset.getMetaData();
                    int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                    while (resultset.next()) {
                        for (int i =1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                            if (metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("id_distrito")) {
                                iddistrito = resultset.getObject(i).toString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        preenchecbmunicipios();    
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                }
            }
        }


        if (!cbmunicipiocliente.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(""))
        {
            query = "select id_municipio from municipios where municipio = '" + cbmunicipiocliente.getSelectedItem().toString() + "';";
            try{
                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
                StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
                ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultset.getMetaData();
                int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                while (resultset.next()) {
                    for (int i =1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                        if (metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("id_municipio")) {
                            idmunicipio = resultset.getObject(i).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

This piece of code fills the contents of the second JComboBox:

```
private void preenchecbmunicipios(){
    if (!iddistrito.equals("VAZIO!!!")) {
        query = "select municipio from municipios where municipios.id_distrito = " + iddistrito + ";";
        populardistritos=true;
        //cbmunicipiocliente.removeAllItems();
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);
            StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultset.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            cbmunicipiocliente.addItem("");
            while (resultset.next()) {
                for (int i =1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    if (metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("municipio")) {
                        cbmunicipiocliente.addItem(resultset.getObject(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            populardistritos=false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"rebentou no 1º catch do cbmunicipio com " + e.toString(),"Inane error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"rebentou no 2º catch do cbmunicipio com " + e.toString(),"Inane error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: No code = Can't help. Press the edit link below your question and add code.

Comment: Thats it... sorry some parts of code is on portuguese language! :S

Comment: While don't you simply create a separate implementation of the `ItemListener` for each combo box, maybe in separate inner classes?

Comment: ... reading the api doc might help as well ;-) Hint: when changing selection from one item to another item two events are fired _by design_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html) tell you that event contains info about originator. So just check for e.getItemSelectable().equals(firstSelectBox) etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to leverage the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513), in which a selection in the first combo replaces the model in a second combo. In that example, `combo1` would hold continents, and the `combo2` model would be set to the one containing countries on the selected continent. The example uses an array, but a `List<ComboBoxModel<String>>` might be a more flexible choice.

Comment: Also consider `Map<String, ComboBoxModel<String>>`.