# JAVA netbeans problems with comboBox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, itemlistener

i am trying to load 2 combo Boxes; the secoond combo box has to be loaded after the change in the first combo.  I am using netbeans and i tried several times but it does not work ...
the items to be loaded have to be the same with the exceptio of the item chosen in the first combo.

```
    private void firstTeamComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt)
{                                                   
        loadSecondTeamComboBox();
    }                                                  

    private void loadSecondTeamComboBox()
    {
        String[] theTeamsInTheLeague2 = league.loadTeamsInLeague(secondTeam.getLeague());
        secondTeamComboBox.addItem("Select a Team");
        for(int i = 0; i < theTeamsInTheLeague2.length; i++)
            if (!(theTeamsInLeague2[i].equals(firstTeam.getLeague()))
                secondTeamComboBox.addItem(theTeamsInTheLeague2[i]);
    }


    private void loadFirstTeamComboBox()
    {
        String[] theTeamsInTheLeague1 = league.loadTeamsInLeague(firstTeam.getLeague());
        firstTeamComboBox.addItem("Select a Team");
        for(int i = 0; i < theTeamsInTheLeague1.length; i++)
            firstTeamComboBox.addItem(theTeamsInTheLeague1[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Well to be honest i do't undestand well what's happening in this related answer

Comment: What exactly is not working? What are the results of your code?

Comment: The problem is that both, the firstTeamCombo and the secondTeamCombo load the same items and in the same moment ... i would like the secondteamCombo to be loaded after having chosen the item of the firstTeamCOmbo ...

Comment: Yes, this is a different problem than the one addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513), but the solution uses the same idea of updating the opposite combo's model.

Comment: Well i studied your example and now it is a little bit clearer (sorry but i am learning ...), but i have more than 20 items in the first Combo Box and i would like after having chosen the item to load the other 19 in the second combo

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to override `setSelectedItem()` in `DefaultComboBoxModel` and keep a reference to `otherTeamModel`, updating it as needed from `allTeamsInTheLeague`.

```
class MyComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {
    private DefaultComboBoxModel otherTeamModel;

    public MyComboBoxModel(DefaultComboBoxModel otherTeamModel) {
        this.otherTeamModel = otherTeamModel;
    }
    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        super.setSelectedItem(item);
        otherTeamModel.removeAllElements();
        // add all allTeamsInTheLeague except item
    }
}
```