# JComboxBox selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have three JComboBoxes; and based on the 1st and 2nd JComboBoxes, the 3rd JComboBox should
show different values. I was able to get the values on the 3rd JComboBox, but for some reason it appends the values with the previous selection. For example,

JCombo1 - A, B, C, D, E, F
   JCombo2 - A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
   JCombo3 - AA1, AA2, AA3, AA4, AA5

Please help.

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding this you asked for append JComboBox1,jComboBox2 (up to item available in jCombo2).

```
 private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.jComboBox3.removeAllItems();
    String boxOneValue = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    for(int i = 0; i < jComboBox2.getItemCount(); i++) {
        jComboBox3.addItem(boxOneValue + jComboBox2.getItemAt(i));
    }
}
```