# How to reset JComboBox in Java in case of country field?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, countries

On Selecting Country Field,
State Field is shown,
AND on Selecting State Feild,
City Field is shown

But in the below code when i select for the first time it works fine but when i select another country
then its States gets added to the previous country's States and similar is the case with City. 
I read about JComboBox.RemoveAll() and DefaultComboBoxModel class but don't know how to use it in current case.
**So,Basically how to reset JComboBox Items?**

Have a look on  **public countryCode{   } class, 
private void stateBoxActionPerformed,

  private void countryBoxActionPerformed    *Functions***

***ANSWER:Here what worked For ME  use   stateBox.removeAllItems() before the code where we r adding states in the list from database .***

Here is code of NetBeans --->

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author System
     */
    public class countryCode extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        DefaultComboBoxModel d1=new  DefaultComboBoxModel();
    Connection con;


    String code,q;
     PreparedStatement ps;
     ResultSet rs;



        /**
         * Creates new form countryCode
         */
        public countryCode() {
            initComponents();
           createConnection();
        }

        void createConnection()
        {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");//Connection String
            String r1="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:";//Open Connection
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(r1,"system","password");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        private void initComponents() {

            countryBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            country = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            stateBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            cityBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            state = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            city = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            countryBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "America", "India", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", " ", " " }));
            countryBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    countryBoxActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            country.setText("Country");

            stateBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { " " }));
            stateBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    stateBoxActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            state.setText("State");

            city.setText("City");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(country, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 87, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(state, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(city, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(cityBox, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(stateBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(countryBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 0, 198, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(95, 95, 95))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(countryBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(country))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(stateBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(state))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(cityBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(city))
                    .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

        private void countryBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_countryBoxActionPerformed


            try {

             //GET STRING
                String coname;
                coname = (String)countryBox.getSelectedItem();
            //STRING QUERY
                q="select * from country where cname=? ";
            //PREPARE STATEMENT
                ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
            //SET STRING
                ps.setString(1,coname);
                 rs=ps.executeQuery();//RESULTSET
                  while(rs.next())
                  {d1.getClass();
                    code=rs.getString("cocode");
                    break;

                  }

              /*  *******************  <!------ANOTHER QUERY------>  ****************************** */

                 //STRING QUERY

                 q="select * from state where cocode=? ";
                //PREPARE STATEMENT
                 ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
                //SET STRING
               ps.setString(1,code);

              ResultSet  rs=ps.executeQuery();
                 while(rs.next())
                  { 
                  String  code=rs.getString("stname");
                    stateBox.addItem(code);
                  }



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        }//GEN-LAST:event_countryBoxActionPerformed

        private void stateBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_stateBoxActionPerformed
        try {
                    /*---------NOW QUERY TO GET STCODE I.E STATECODE   REPEAT HERE STEPS WHAT WE DID IN COUNTRY -----------*/

                    //GET STRING
                    String stname;
                    stname = (String)stateBox.getSelectedItem();
                //STRING QUERY
                    q="select * from state where stname=? ";
                //PREPARE STATEMENT
                    ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
                //SET STRING
                    ps.setString(1,stname);
                     rs=ps.executeQuery();//RESULTSET
                      while(rs.next())
                      {
                        code=rs.getString("stcode");
                        break;

                      }

                  /*  *******************  <!------ANOTHER QUERY------>  ****************************** */

                     //STRING QUERY
                     q="select * from city where stcode=? ";
                    //PREPARE STATEMENT
                     ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
                    //SET STRING
                    ps.setString(1,code);
                    rs=ps.executeQuery();
                     while(rs.next())
                      {
                        code=rs.getString("ciname");
                        cityBox.addItem(code);
                      }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }






        }//GEN-LAST:event_stateBoxActionPerformed

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(countryCode.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(countryCode.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(countryCode.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(countryCode.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new countryCode().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
        private javax.swing.JLabel city;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox cityBox;
        private javax.swing.JLabel country;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox countryBox;
        private javax.swing.JLabel state;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox stateBox;
        // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    }
```

Comment: That was too much code dude !!!!

Comment: `I read about JComboBox.RemoveAll() .. but don't kno how to use it in current case`- you invoke the `removeAll()` method `BEFORE` you start looping and adding more items using the `addItem()` method.

Comment: Please attempt to create a SSCCE.

Comment: removeAll halts the Frame,when i placed it between      ps.setString(1,code);
            removeAll();
          ResultSet  rs=ps.executeQuery();

Comment: Try this simpler [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513).

Comment: Here what worked for me :  stateBox.removeAllItems();//Used To Reset Combo BOx just before the while block (here while block where we are adding states).

Comment: So,basically function removeAllItems() is used to reset the JComboBox or to get Default Combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try using removeAllItems() method. You should call this function before you start adding items to your combo box. so your code should look like this

```
/**
  *do something here
 **/

jComboBox.removeAllItems();

/**
*do something else here
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoveAll method befor adding new items to your combobox just befor  while loop.
You can also use array list.