# How do I lose focus on a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcombobox, keylistener

I have a `JComboBox` with an key listener.

When I hit `<enter>`, I fire off some action, **and then I need to to lose focus on the `JComboBox`**!

To focus on it, I can do `JComboBoxObject.grabFocus();`

But doing `transferFocus()` to get the focus to a next element (I don't care WHERE the focus goes, just away from combo box) does NOT work.

**Doing `grabFocus()` from another combo box works, but seems like a pretty annoying hack to me. Is there a better solution?**

Comment: unrelated: sigh ... don't use keylisteners .. related: transferFocus (used on the currently focused compoent) should work, if it doesn't better show a SSCCE demonstrating what _exactly_ you are doing/trying to achieve. BTW, you did read the tutorial on how to use JComboBox, didn't you? It has something to say on low-level listeners and (potentially - you can't really know) compound  components :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you to first use the

> .getNextFocusableComponent()

and then use the

> .requestFocusInWindow()

that means Implementing it like this,

> JComboBox.getNextFocusableComponent().requestFocusInWindow();

One important note is that **.getNextFocusableComponent()** has become obsolete but it can work really better, you can use it but If you have any other solution, I would prefer not using this.

Answer (score 3):

Updated: Starting from this two-combo [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513), adding either of these lines to the `actionPerformed()` implementation seems to do what you want.

```
combo1.transferFocus();
combo2.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Comment: you don't really recommend hard-coding the other component, do you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra is right: I took "don't care" a bit too literally; you should ask the `FocusTraversalPolicy` of the enclosing `Container`, as the deprecated `getNextFocusableComponent()` API suggests.

Comment: actually, asking the traversalPolicy is too low-level (you would have to walk up until you find the one that's applicable, also checking the isTraversalPolicyProvider properties and other thingies that I don't remember) - component.transferFocus should just work fine.