# What is the proper way to feed data to JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

What is the proper way to feed data to `JComboBox`? I am trying to feed a `String` array to the `JComboBox` that was initiated before, and I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Code:

```
public void readPlayers(){
    String[] arr = new String[currentGames.get(currentGame).currentPlayers()];
    for(int i = 0; i <currentGames.get(currentGame).currentPlayers(); i++){
        arr[i] = "Player " + (i + 1) + currentGames.get(currentGame).getPlayer(i).getId();
    }
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(arr);
    playersBox.setModel(  model);
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Edit: My problem here is that I need to update the data in the `JComboBox` every time I want to use it because the strings in the array might be different than when I used the combo box the first time.

Comment: What's the data type of `currentGames.get(currentGame).currentPlayers()`? A List? Map? ...

Comment: Is it multithreaded? Make sure there is no race condition. E.g. `currentGames.get(currentGame).currentPlayers()` could potentially return number which will become non-actual during the loop execution, should there be another thread adding/removing elements to/from the list. Check GUI elements with static data first.

Comment: `currentGames.get(currentGame).currentPlayers()` return an int and `currentGames.get(currentGame).getPlayer(i).getId()` returns a string

Comment: it is not multithreaded. My problem here is that i need to update the data in the JcomboBox every time I want to use because the Strings in the array might be different than when i used the ComboBox the first time. The compiler is giving me the exception when the line `playersBox.setModel(  model);` is invoked

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the `NullPointerException` is incidental to the nominal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to update the data in the `JComboBox` every time I want to use it because the strings in the array might be different than when I used the combo box the first time.

Although it is sometimes appropriate to *replace* the `ComboBoxModel` using `setModel()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513), you may want to *update* the model in place using [`removeAllElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#removeAllElements--) followed by a loop that invokes [`addElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#addElement-E-).

Comment: Thx. It worked with the alternative way you introduced